# Annotations vs. Javadoc in Maven Mojos

Tags: java, maven

I'am somehow confused about annotating fields in my maven mojo. E.g. for retrieving the `MavenProject` instance the code would look like this

```
/**
 * @property property="${project}"
 * @readonly
 * @required
 */
private MavenProject project;
```

or it could look like this (does the same)

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

You can even combine both variants, which also works somehow.

1. What exactly is the difference between those variants?
2. Is one of the methods deprecated / outdated? What is the preferred way?
3. Variant "javadoc": What is the point in encoding program logic into a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc variant is the old method for specifying the information that should go into plugin.xml descriptor. Java Annotations were only introduced in Java 5.

The [Proposal for Java 5 Annotations for MOJOs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+5+Annotations+for+Plugins) describes some of the advantages of using annotations over Javadoc tags:

> Using java 5 annotations instead of javadoc ones have multiple benefits:
>
> - compile-time checks for plugin metadata, with enums for some annotations
>
>   inheritance support
>
>   annotations are supported in most IDEs, providing code-completion and syntactic checks

Additionally, the [maven-plugin-plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) mentions that it allows to have MOJO super classes in different projects and their source code does not need to be available.

#### Which method to use?

I would use Java 5 annotations for the reasons named above and also because of the point you make in your third question: program logic should not be encoded in a comment.